# I am not Able to check spelling in Text Area input ,by clicking Spell-Check icon

Tags: html, angular7

I have used spell check icon so that once I click on this icon the input data in the text area should be spell checked to show a red line below

[image]

Comment: Please fill your question which is not completed and also explain the problem you are facing with the code that you have used..

Comment: i have putted image, when i click on that spell check ,it should check the spelling in text area Data

Comment: <div>
      <mat-form-field  appearance="outline"style="
      width: 500px;
      height: 80px;" >
    
        <textarea matInput    value=""    placeholder="Message Text" rows="10" cols="100"   > 
        
        
        </textarea>
        <button  style="
        padding: -6px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 45px;
        float: right;
      
        position: absolute;
       
        margin-left: -76px;">spellcheck <i class="material-icons" spellcheck=true >spellcheck</i></button>

      </mat-form-field></div>

Answer (score 0):

`spellcheck = true` has to be associated with any text tag or input tag as follows:

```
<textarea matInput value="" placeholder="Message Text" rows="10" cols="100" spellcheck=true > </textarea>
```